# A regular sequence in a quotient by a "half lattice" defined by a toric manifold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, cohomology, toric-varieties

I am interested in some properties of polynomial algebras associated with smooth compact toric varieties. Recall that a toric manifold can be obtained as a quotient $$P^{-1}(p) / \mathbb{K}$$ by the action of a torus $\mathbb{K} \subset (S^1)^n$, of a regular level of the momentum map $P : \mathbb{C}^n \to \text{Lie}(\mathbb{K})^*$ of this action. We denote by $\mathbb{R}^k = \text{Lie}(\mathbb{K}) \subset \mathbb{R}^n = \text{Lie}((S^1)^n)$, and by $\mathbb{Z}^k \subset \mathbb{Z}^n$ and $\mathbb{C}^k \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ their respective lattices and complexifications. We suppose that $k < n$ (that is the toric manifold is not $\mathbb{C} P^{n-1}$).

---

Denoting $u=(u_1,...,u_n)$, consider the $\mathbb{C}[u]$-module $\mathbb{C}[u,u^{-1}]$ of polynomial functions on $(\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 0 \})^n$, and let $I$ denote the ideal of $\mathbb{C}[u]$ generated by polynomials vanishing on the subspace $\mathbb{C}^k \subset \mathbb{C}^n$.

I would like to show that the $n-k$ generators of $I$ form a regular sequence in the following $\mathbb{C}[u]$-module:
$$ \mathbb{C}[u,u^{-1}] \ / \  J_r \mathbb{C}[u,u^{-1}],$$
where $J_r$ is the $\mathbb{C}[u]$-submodule of $\mathbb{C}[u,u^{-1}]$ defined in the following way: 
$$J_r := \langle u^l : l \in \mathbb{Z}^k \text{ and } p(l) \geq r \rangle, $$

---

I know the following : $\mathbb{C}[u] / (I+ J_r \cap \mathbb{C}[u])$ is non-trivial and finite dimensional as a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space. To prove this, I used compactness with the fact that $p$ is a regular value of the momentum map, and showed that the zero set of the ideal $I + J_r \cap \mathbb{C}[u]$ is reduced to $0$. A version of the Nullstellensatz says then that $I + J_r \cap \mathbb{C}[u]$ must contain powers of all the monomials $u_1,...,u_n$. Hence the quotient is finite dimensional.

---

It seems that the fact that $I + J_r \cap \mathbb{C}[u]$ behaves in this particular way implies the regularity of the sequence. However, I cannot see how. I will be grateful to anyone that will help.